# Detecting the module in python (which sends data to the GUI thread)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

So I wrote this software which used to implement 4 tabs (now 8). Now, every tab is its own QThread, plus one general GUI thread, obviously. The worker threads (tab threads) send data back to the GUI thread when this needs updating. For example, I have a statusBar text in the GUI thread which needs to be updated every time worker thread does something. I'm using the SIGNAL/SLOT for that, and the way I detect an incoming SIGNAL is like this:

```
def setStatus(self, status):
    #Defining SIGNAL sender
    self.sender = QObject().sender()        
    if "module1" in str(self.sender):
        self.module1CurrentStatus.setText(status)
```

Now this works and all, but like I said, the software has grown from implementing 4 tabs to implementing 8 tabs. Is there a better way to implement this, instead of using `sender()`? I'm simply looking for something that can be written only once for all the modules, a way for the GUI to know automatically which thread the SIGNAL came from. I know that I could write a separate SIGNAL for every module, but I accomplish nothing with that.

Comment: I am probably missing something here. Why don't you connect the signal from the thread to the `setText` of appropriate widget instead of this intermediate function to set statuses?

Comment: @Avaris because I can't use the setText function in the non-GUI (worker) thread.

Comment: Still... You connect them in the main (GUI) thread. This `setStatus` method is there, isn't it? And, you create your worker threads in the main thread, don't you? If you can connect them to `setStatus`, you can connect them to `module1CurrentStatus.setText` as well. Maybe it is better if you share more code to provide proper context.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you could use a [`QSignalMapper`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) to re-emit the signals with an identifier.

Answer (score -1):

The module name can be acquired via `__name__`, unless it is the file being run as a script .

Comment: Well in that case I'd just replace QSender with __name__, accomplishing nothing.